# Issue with 2016 developer edition install

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2016, windows-10

Issue with 2016 developer edition install on new windows 10 machine.  Not finding any docs or similar issues posted.

> An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
>
> Component name:                SQL Server 2008 Setup Support Files
>
> Component error code:          1935
>
> Error description:             An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.ATL,version="8.0.50727.1833",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x800736B3.

Answer (score 2):

Given [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kHf5.jpg), I can imagine you are selecting to install every single feature during setup:

> [image]

I would start with just the set of features you need, since selecting everything - especially if you don't actually need everything - creates a whole bunch of dependencies for little gain.

You can always go back and add features as you realize you need them.